# Is there a way to copy Legend from one diagram to another?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have some common legend to be followed across project for all diagrams.
I see no way to copy the Legend from one EA diagram to another.
is there a way out for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no issue using Ctrl-C while the legend is selected and using Ctrl-V in the target diagram.

Comment: Strange, it worked :). last time I tried this it failed.